# Detect color pages or BW pages in PDF

Tags: itext

Is there any way that I can detect color pages in a PDF file?
For example I have a PDF file with 5 pages, and the first and last page are in color. How can I detect the color pages? Can iText do it?
Now my solution is to convert PDF to images and then detect images color or black&white, but it takes too long time to do it, I need a fast way.
Convert pdf to image by Adobe Acrobat Code as fellows

```
public static void ConvertPDF2Image(string pdfInputPath, string imageOutputPath,
        string imageName, int startPageNum, int endPageNum, ImageFormat imageFormat, double resolution)
    {
        Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc pdfDoc = null;
        Acrobat.CAcroPDPage pdfPage = null;
        Acrobat.CAcroRect pdfRect = null;
        Acrobat.CAcroPoint pdfPoint = null;
        // Create the document (Can only create the AcroExch.PDDoc object using late-binding)
        // Note using VisualBasic helper functions, have to add reference to DLL
        pdfDoc = (Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc)Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc", "");
        // validate parameter
        if (!pdfDoc.Open(pdfInputPath)) { throw new FileNotFoundException(); }
        if (!Directory.Exists(imageOutputPath)) { Directory.CreateDirectory(imageOutputPath); }
        if (startPageNum <= 0) { startPageNum = 1; }
        if (endPageNum > pdfDoc.GetNumPages() || endPageNum <= 0) { endPageNum = pdfDoc.GetNumPages(); }
        if (startPageNum > endPageNum) { int tempPageNum = startPageNum; startPageNum = endPageNum; endPageNum = startPageNum; }
        if (imageFormat == null) { imageFormat = ImageFormat.Jpeg; }
        if (resolution <= 0) { resolution = 1; }
        // start to convert each page
        for (int i = startPageNum; i <= endPageNum; i++)
        {
            pdfPage = (Acrobat.CAcroPDPage)pdfDoc.AcquirePage(i - 1);
            pdfPoint = (Acrobat.CAcroPoint)pdfPage.GetSize();
            pdfRect = (Acrobat.CAcroRect)Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject("AcroExch.Rect", "");
            int imgWidth = (int)((double)pdfPoint.x * resolution);
            int imgHeight = (int)((double)pdfPoint.y * resolution);
            pdfRect.Left = 0;
            pdfRect.right = (short)imgWidth;
            pdfRect.Top = 0;
            pdfRect.bottom = (short)imgHeight;
            // Render to clipboard, scaled by 100 percent (ie. original size)
            // Even though we want a smaller image, better for us to scale in .NET
            // than Acrobat as it would greek out small text
            pdfPage.CopyToClipboard(pdfRect, 0, 0, (short)(100 * resolution));
            IDataObject clipboardData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            if (clipboardData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            {
                Bitmap pdfBitmap = (Bitmap)clipboardData.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
                pdfBitmap.Save(Path.Combine(imageOutputPath, imageName) + i.ToString() + "." + imageFormat.ToString(), imageFormat);
                pdfBitmap.Dispose();
            }
        }
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pdfPage);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pdfRect);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pdfDoc);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pdfPoint);
```

}

```
////detect image  Color  or black and white as fellows 
Bitmap box1 = new Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image);
Color c = new Color()
int rr, gg, bb; 
for(int i=0;i<PictureBox1.Width;i++){
for(int j=0;j<PictureBox1.Height;j++){
c= box1.GetPixel(i,j);
rr= c.R; gg=c.g;bb=c.B;       
if（c ==Color.Black||c= Color.White）{
     MessageBox.Show("black and white dot")
  }
  else {
     if(rr==gg==bb){
         MessageBox.Show("Gray dot");
     }
     else {
         MessageBOx.Show("Color dot")；
      } 
  }
```

}
}

Comment: Which version of iText? 5 or 7? How long is too long, in milliseconds? Can you share an example file and your current code?

Comment: itext version5  .a 300 pages pdf ,convert to images about  one second one page , so it will take  about 5 minutes  convert  to images and  then detect images color black and white also almost one image one seconds , so a 300 pages pdf it will take 5 minutes to 10 minutes to finished the work.

Comment: That is not a lot of information. I was hoping for a sample file and your current code.

Comment: Hi Ameddd Van Gasse,thanks your reply, i upload code please check,for the sample file because is  a little large , about 100mb ， how to send it to you ?  and also you can chose any pdf  about 200 to 300 pages pdf to do the test .  and i want to know  can itext  detect color page and black white page directly ? such as  i roop every pdf page and i got all pdf object from every page ,and analysis pdf object is color or black white?

Comment: *"i want to know can itext detect color page and black white page directly"* - what exactly *is* a colour page or a black & white page for you? Your code indicates you mean that a page is black&white if a bitmap image rendered from it in a single, given resolution has only exactly black or exactly white pixels. There may be pages which rendered at some higher resolution show coloured pixels. Interpolation in images might (depending on resolution and renderer) sometimes show non-black&white pixels and sometimes not.

Comment: Hi  mkl ,thanks your reply. yes  that's  a good question "what exactly is a colour page or a black & white page for you? " you asked .

Comment: Hi mkl,it's a good question "what exactly is a colour page or a black & white page for you? "until now i don't find a good solution to do the work , back to your question  i open pdf  file and  use  pitStop(a kind of Adobe Acrobat plug to analysis pdf structure)i select object in pdf to look color,cmyk ,rgb,gray,if pdf object is gray then it's a black and white,if cmyk color and c m y are not the same then is color , and if RGB color, R,G,B are not the same then is color

Comment: The problem with that approach: some object might by itself have colour but some other object overlapping it might change it to b&w.

Comment: _"what exactly is a colour page or a black & white page for you?"_ - and that is why I asked to see the code: so we can know *exactly* what black&white means for you.

Comment: "The problem with that approach: some object might by itself have colour but some other object overlapping it might change it to b&w." - which implies that the PDF must be *rendered* in some way to find out the final color, at a certain resolution, as it is presented to the human eye. I think your current approach, for your specific use case, is already ok at a high level but you need to work on the specific details to improve performance.

Comment: Take a look at the iText source code on GitHub, more specifically the tests. You'll see that we use `CompareTool` in our tests. `CompareTool` uses Ghostscript and Imagemagic. It can do visual comparison of PDF files. You could adapt that to check if an image rendered from a PDF page is B/W or color. Using Ghostscript & Imagemagic might be a lot faster than your current solution - speed is one of the reasons we use it in the iText tests. `CompareTool` is in `kernel.utils` (iText 7) and pay attention to `compareVisually`.